# Cannot find MetaModelica.* functions in OpenModelica (OMEdit). Need intBitXor()

Tags: openmodelica

See title.

[The documentation](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/MetaModelica.html) indicates the existence of the needed function, but I can't seem to find it in any of the standard OM libraries or builtins.

Where to find `MetaModelica`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MetaModelica is a language extension of Modelica, see [[1]](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=626ed731fbbd28474985b55cc67845c9285dc075), and used by the Modelica tool OpenModelica.
The function `intBitXor` is a internal function used by the OpenModelica Compiler (OMC) and not usable outside of the compiler itself. So you need to define such a function yourself or search for a Modelica library that provides it already.

[[1]](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=626ed731fbbd28474985b55cc67845c9285dc075) : Fritzson Peter, Adrian Pop, and Peter Aronsson. Towards
Comprehensive Meta-Modeling and Meta-Programming
Capabilities in Modelica. In Proceedings of the 4th
International Modelica Conference, Hamburg, Germany,
March 7-8, 2005

Comment: Thanks, quite peculiar that I couldn't readily find such a lib though... Seems like a no-brainer, especially for a language that has access to a C-compiler?